# Spring data jpa predicate hint index for mysql (Jpa + Hibernate)

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an application using Spring data Jpa/Hibernate (Mysql database). I have specific query using Spring data in this way:

```
myRepository.findAll(filterSpecifications, pageable);
```

My query is too slow. I need to use index created in MY table to be able to query fast.

```
from MyTable table FORCE INDEX(Mytable_createdAt_index)
```

Which is the way to say Jpa force using this index with specifications?

Comment: Why do you think that using an index would be faster when performing selecting all the rows from a table?

Comment: I have tested the same query with force index with better response time. Without using this approach took 30 seconds. Using describe command shows MySQL using  another index.

Comment: Oh sorry, completely missed that you are passing specification and pagination. I only saw the `findAll` part.

Comment: You'd need to provide your query specifically with a @Query annotation, can't be combined with a `Specification`. So I guess that leaves you with a custom method assembling the SQL your own. Or maybe you can encode the force index in a view?